# jquery .not() to execute method on click of all elements but not some elements

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I want to hide a box on clicking anywhere in document but not in few areas so I wrote this code:

```
$(document).not('#color_picker,#selected_color_box,#color_picker_choose,#choose_color_box').click(function(event){
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $('#color_picker').css('visibility','hidden');
                        })
```

but it now never show the box, seems that it execute the function on click anywhere whether user click on elements which are in `.not()`, while this function shouldn't execute if user click on elements which are in not.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: yeah, that doesn't do what you think it does. the .not does absolutely nothing because the document *can't* match the selector inside the .not. You'll need an if statement inside the event that compares `event.target` to the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.not()` just filters the current selection to elements that don't match the selector. `document` doesn't match the selector, so no change is made to the collection.

You should instead use event delegation with a selector that matches all elements that are not your target elements.

```
$(document).on('click',':not(#color_picker,#selected_color_box,#color_picker_choose,#choose_color_box)',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#color_picker').css('visibility','hidden');
})
```

or you can compare the `event.target.id` to your list of id's to ignore:

```
var idArr = ['color_picker','selected_color_box','color_picker_choose','choose_color_box'];
$(document).on('click',function(event) {
    if ( idArr.indexOf(event.target.id) == -1 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#color_picker').css('visibility','hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: The second way seems easier to add new elements to ignore. Why `indexOf`, could lead to false positives?

Comment: And it can be dynamically generated easier than the :not

Comment: @JuanMendes what would be better, `$.inArray`? $.inArray internally uses [].indexOf

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it was a call to `Array.indexOf`, not `String.indexOf`, nevermind

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$(document).find("*").not('#color_picker,#selected_color_box,#color_picker_choose,#choose_color_box')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting all the elements and then filtering

```
$('*').not('#color_picker,#selected_color_box,#color_picker_choose,#choose_color_box').click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         $('#color_picker').css('visibility','hidden');
    })
```

Comment: As long as you don't add elements dynamically, but popups are usually added dynamically

Comment: Yes, but I didn't see anything in the question that implies the need for popups or dynamic elements.

Comment: The question is talking about clicking anywhere else on the page and dismissing the box... Very likely that it's created dynamically by clicking something else on the screen. It could work, just a warning.